# Enabel Excel Autofilter when export the data from gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, gridview, export-to-excel

**I really appreciate if anyone can help me on how can I enable the filter feature on Excel when exporting the data from gridview.( Excel Autofilter)**

```
 public ActionResult ExportToExcel(List<EventViewModel> list)
    {
        try
        {
           // Main
             GridView gv = new GridView();
            gv.DataSource = list.ToList();
            gv.DataBind();

            Response.ClearContent();
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Charset = "";
            Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment; filename=filename.xls");//Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=Excel.xls");
            Response.ContentType = "application/excel";

            StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
            HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);
            gv.RenderControl(htw);
            Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
            Response.Flush();
            Response.End();

            return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
        catch (System.Exception e)
        { 
            return View("Error");
        }
    }
```

Comment: `Hanouf D` what do you get when you type the following exactly in a google search box [C# exporting the data from gridview.( Excel Autofilter)](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20exporting%20the%20data%20from%20gridview.(%20excel%20autofilter)) ?

Comment: They all using autofilter='all' from the view or    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library with asp.net web pages. but I am using ASP.NET MVC 4 - razor view>

Answer (score 0):

Your code exports an HTML file with XLS extension. It is not a binary XLS file and you cannot have an Excel autofilter, not using your code.

If you can't use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel library, you can search for another Excel library that exports real Excel files.

I use [EasyXLS Excel library](http://www.easyxls.com/net-excel-library). This code exports the datatable of the gridview and adds an autofilter and it use this library:

```
// Create an instance of the class that exports Excel files, having one sheet
ExcelDocument xls = new ExcelDocument(1);

// Get the sheet
ExcelWorksheet xlsWorksheet = (ExcelWorksheet)xls.easy_getSheetAt(0);

// Create a dataset that keeps the gridview datatable
DataSet dataSet = new DataSet();
dataSet.Tables.Add((DataTable)gridView.DataSource);

// Insert the dataset into sheet
xlsWorksheet.easy_insertDataSet(dataSet, true);

//Add AutoFilter
ExcelFilter xlsFilter = xlsWorksheet.easy_getFilter();
xlsFilter.setAutoFilter("A1:E1");

// Choose a name for the xls file 
string fileName = "filename.xls";
Response.Clear();
Response.Buffer = true;
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + fileName);
Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";

// Export Excel file and prompt the "Open or Save Dialog Box" 
xls.easy_WriteXLSFile(Response.OutputStream);

// Dispose memory
xls.Dispose();
Response.End();
```

For more details on formatting read this link about [export gridview to Excel](http://www.easyxls.com/manual/FAQ/export-gridview-to-excel.html).